# Replacing/Converting 1 to A with Oracle/PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Firstly, I greatly appreciate any feedback that anyone can offer. I am using Oracle SQL Developer, Version 4.0.2.15, Build 15.21.

I know and understand that many, many similar questions have been asked, as I've searched around on stackoverflow as well as the rest of the internet. However, the corresponding answers are either too vague or too extravagant, and attempt to do things that are way over my head and not what I am trying to accomplish. I am extremely new to SQL and haven't seriously done any coding since I did Java about 12 years ago. So please understand that something simple to you, is not so simple and obvious to me.

My bare-bones endstate that I am shooting for is taking a pre-existing Oracle Table Column, which is called 'service_level', that has parameters of 1-3, and making them A-C (where A=1, B=2, C=3). The reason for this is that I have an ArcGIS gdB featureclass that has a corresponding column, called 'MaintServi', with the parameters of A-C. I am going to join them using ArcToolbox once I have converted/replaced the 1-3 to A-C, and have exported them from Oracle into an Arc gdB as another table. The reason being is that the featureclass (obviously) has geometry, but this particular Oracle table does not.

From what I have gathered I know (or think) I will need to use something like:

```
chr(ord('a') + 3)
```

^ Where I will need to use/call upon the chr/ord functions. However, due to my inexperience, I cannot think of how to properly call this without getting an error. Below is what I have for my query thus far (but without chr/ord). I just need to figure out how to correctly insert it into my query to achieve the desired results.

```
SELECT v_wv_wp_crew.*,
   Substr(v_wv_wp_crew.winter_supp_id, 1, 6)  AS CostCenter,
   Substr(v_wv_wp_crew.winter_supp_id, 8, 11) AS Crew_Supp_ID
FROM   v_wv_wp_crew
WHERE  crew_on_road >= '13-FEB-12'
   AND ( operation = 2
   OR operation = 3 );
```

Thanks again and hopefully I have complied with the posting rules of stackoverflow.

@ Mark J. Bobak - 
When implementing his ideas I get either this (Like I said, i'm not sure how to insert it properly without receiving an error)

```
SELECT v_wv_wp_crew.*,
   Substr(v_wv_wp_crew.winter_supp_id, 1, 6)  AS CostCenter,
   Substr(v_wv_wp_crew.winter_supp_id, 8, 11) AS Crew_Supp_ID
FROM   v_wv_wp_crew
WHERE  crew_on_road >= '13-FEB-12'
AND ( operation = 2
          OR operation = 3 )
          UNION ALL
WITH service_level as (select 1 service_level from dual
union all
select 2 service_level from dual union all
select 3 service_level from dual)
select decode(service_level,1,'A',2,'B',3,'C') from service_level;
```

I receive the following error:

*ORA-32034: unsupported use of WITH clause
32034. 00000 -  "unsupported use of WITH clause"
*Cause:    Inproper use of WITH clause because one of the following two reasons
           1. nesting of WITH clause within WITH clause not supported yet
           2. For a set query, WITH clause can't be specified for a branch.
           3. WITH clause can't sepecified within parentheses.
*Action:   correct query and retry
Error at Line: 14 Column: 25*

- Or I receive an output of only 3 rows (A, B, C) if I run the query separately - sorry I don't have enough reputation to post the image yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `DECODE()` function.  Something like this should work:

```
with list_of_digits as (select 1 col_a from dual
                        union all
                        select 2 col_a from dual
                        union all
                        select 3 col_a from dual
                        union all
                        select 4 col_a from dual)
select decode(col_a,1,'A',2,'B',3,'C','Other') from list_of_digits;
```

Using your query, try this:

```
WITH service_level as (select 1 service_level from dual
union all
select 2 service_level from dual union all
select 3 service_level from dual)
select decode(service_level,1,'A',2,'B',3,'C') from service_level
union all
SELECT v_wv_wp_crew.*,
   Substr(v_wv_wp_crew.winter_supp_id, 1, 6)  AS CostCenter,
   Substr(v_wv_wp_crew.winter_supp_id, 8, 11) AS Crew_Supp_ID
FROM   v_wv_wp_crew
WHERE  crew_on_road >= '13-FEB-12'
AND ( operation = 2
          OR operation = 3 );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately, this is what I get with your suggestion (edited post above).

Comment: What version of Oracle are you running?

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
"CORE 11.2.0.3.0 Production"
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production

Comment: Mark, thank you very much for your edit (sorry I didn't see it at first). It worked great! The only issue I had is that it will only run with your code, I unfortunately receive the error '•ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns' when attempting to use my bit of code in there as well. Either way, thank you!

Comment: As to the ORA-01789, make sure that each query being UNIONed together has the same number and types of columns in the select list.  Obviously, I don;t have access to your database, so I may have missed something.

Comment: Mark, yes thank you for the advice. I understand what the error is, just not sure how to incorporate that query into my other query (which pulls from the same table), in order to have it all nicely union together. Your code uses 'SELECT' for 1-3 (which is part of the column service_level). This isn't compatible with the 'SELECT' of the rest of my code or am I missing a much more obvious way of remedying this?

Answer (score 2):

`ord` isn't an Oracle function. The equivalent Oracle function is `ASCII`. However, even substituting in the correct function, I don't see how that gets you what you want.

It seems most likely that you just want to add a column (I'd use `case` to translate the values):

```
SELECT v_wv_wp_crew.*,
   Substr(v_wv_wp_crew.winter_supp_id, 1, 6)  AS CostCenter,
   Substr(v_wv_wp_crew.winter_supp_id, 8, 11) AS Crew_Supp_ID,
   case service_level
     when '1' then 'a'
     when '2' then 'b'
     when '3' then 'c'
   end as service_level_alpha
FROM   v_wv_wp_crew
WHERE  crew_on_road >= '13-FEB-12'
   AND ( operation = 2
   OR operation = 3 );
```

If you want to return this column as `service_level`, then you'll need to return the full list of columns instead of using the asterisk.

---

Since this is a straight-forward character swap, you could use `translate` to really streamline the operation: `translate(service_level,'123','abc')`. However, I vastly prefer `case` over either `decode` or `translate` for readability

Comment: Thank you for your help Allan. I received the error "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected" - Which is showing that it is expected before 'case service_level'.

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using (try select * from v$version)?

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
"CORE 11.2.0.3.0 Production"
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production